# BeatifulSoup get responce with " • " in content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to solve a Problem with beatifulSoup.
I have content

```
content =""" 
<div class="topinfo title">Kategorie: <b>Serie</b> • Datum: <b>15.11.16</b> • IMDB: <a href="http://dontknow.me/at/?http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/">
</div>
"""
```

What I want to have is the "Datum" field but I cant get is work.
I tried:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser") 
info = {}
for details in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "topinfo title"}):
    info[details.text.strip(':')] = details.next_sibling.strip('\n')
```

but I cant get it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what your need, but this maybe work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc ='''<div class="topinfo title">Kategorie: <b>Serie</b> • Datum: <b>15.11.16</b> • IMDB: <a href="http://dontknow.me/at/?http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/">
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml')
soup.get_text()
```

out:

```
'Kategorie: Serie • Datum: 15.11.16 • IMDB: \n'
```

if your get this point, you can play with it whatever you want.